# re-direct a domain to a sub-domain + make it https

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, https, hosting, web-hosting

this is kinda an odd one:

I need my site to do two things (one of which is already working):

1. if a user tried to access the domain via HTTP:// it is replaced with https:// - this is for SEO in google and to make the user feel more secure -
2. the site folder that is used to load the website needs to be the subdomain folder of the site

Oddly the second part of this is working and I figured out - however I'm not sure how to merge these two requests:

HTACCSESS

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^trippy\.co\.nz$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.trippy\.co\.nz$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !update.trippy.co.nz/
RewriteRule (.*) /update.trippy.co.nz/$1 [L]
```

But I'm not sure how to make the site display as

https://trippy.co.nz/

I have tried:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} update\.trippy\.co\.nz [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://update.trippy.co.nz/$1 [R,L]
```

but then the web address displays as: https://update.trippy.co.nz

and I need to remain as https://trippy.co.nz/

Any help here would really great and I know its a odd situation to be in.

THanks,

Wally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...but then the web address displays as: `https://update.trippy.co.nz`

You would seem to be redirecting to the subdomain itself, not the subdomain's subdirectory, as you appear to be doing in the first rule. You may also be putting the directives in the wrong order - the external redirect needs to go first - otherwise you are going to expose the subdomain's subdirectory, which does not appear to be the intention.

Try the following instead:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect HTTP to HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?trippy\.co\.nz [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R,L]

# Rewrite all requests to the subdomain's subdirectory
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?trippy\.co\.nz [NC]
RewriteRule !^update\.trippy\.co\.nz/ /update.trippy.co.nz%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

No need for the extra condition in the 2nd rule block, as the check can be performed directly in the `RewriteRule` and use the `REQUEST_URI` server variable instead of the `$1` backreference in the *substitution* string.

That that `R` by itself is a temporary (302) redirect. You may want to change that to `R=301` (permanent) once you have confirmed this is working OK.

Comment: This worked 100% how I needed it to work - thank you so so much! - as a side bar: do you have any recommendations for where to learn to write htaccsess, does that specific skill fit into the role of DEV OPS? I'm trying to quantify the skill -- again thank you so so much for your help

Comment: You're welcome. "learn to write htaccsess" - by htaccess, are you referring to mod_rewrite? My goto resource is the [Apache docs (for mod_rewrite)](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/) - although that may not be everyone's cup-of-tea and `.htaccess` isn't only mod_rewrite. The Apache config covers a range of disciplines, but I would say `.htaccess` is firmly in the realm of the developer/programmer. It's part of the userland code-base and can be distributed with the application. I'm a web-developer and I use `.htaccess` as part of application development (and SEO).

Comment: I've seen others reference "Apache mod_rewrite" by Rich Bowen - although I have not read it myself. As far as I can tell, it was published in 2006 (which would seem to predate Apache 2.2) and hasn't been updated since? (Things have changed a bit since then.)

Comment: Ok Awesome that gives me some pointers to start looking into, so thank you for that: not to let this drag on to long as your answer was super helpful, but can I ask, when you mention adjusting your htaccsess for SEO is that by using htaccsess for caching your websites content? I've been looking at how to do that but am drawing something of a blank, and pointers (or just, what could be done with htacsess would be amazing) -

Comment: "SEO-related" is perhaps more accurate. Yes, that could include browser caching. As well as URL-rewriting (pretty URLs), canonical redirects (and/or setting rel=canonical headers), content migration rewrites/redirects, setting other HTTP response headers like X-Robots-Tag (related to indexing). Obviously, you can do some of that in your application instead - and it may be preferable to do so. Browser caching is more easily managed using mod_expires (`ExpiresByType` etc.) - this sets the appropriate HTTP response headers for you based on the mime-type of the response.